# While using Sublime Text I came across this error

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3 in a Windows 10 OS. Till today when I opened it to do some coding, I showed some error, Saying:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['mxmlc', 'C:\\Users\\Agniva Roy\\Desktop\\Python Files\\Virtual `Assistant.py', '-library-path+=/libs',` 
'-output', '/bin/.swf', '-debug=false', '-static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true']]


[dir: C:\Users\Agniva Roy\Desktop\Python Files]
[path: C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-14.0.2.12-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Users\Agniva Roy\Scripts\;C:\Users\Agniva Roy\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Agniva Roy\PycharmProjects\Scripts\;C:\Users\Agniva Roy\PycharmProjects\;C:\Users\Agniva Roy\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Agniva Roy\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.2\bin;;C:\Users\Agniva Roy\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin]
[Finished]
```

Comment: It looks like you have a missing file in your project.. `Assistant.py`. Also, I maybe suggest you to edit your post to delete sensible information in file paths (names etc).

Comment: @ju95ju actually, it's the executable that can't be found - that's what WinError 2 is. I'm writing an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

The system most likely can't find the `mxmlc` executable, which is why it's giving you a WinError 2. You should edit your build system and put in the full path to its location, similar to:

```js
"cmd": "C:\\path\\to\\mxmlc", $file, '-library-path+=/libs', '-output', '/bin/.swf', '-debug=false', '-static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true'
```